# C++: undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, identifier

I have searched quite thoroughly on this but can't seem to find an answer.

I have a "bank" class that naturally has a vector. here is one of the functions with the problematic part:

```
int bank::open(op *o, int id)
{
account *acc = new account();
if (search(o->account))
    return ACCOUNT_EXISTS;
accounts.push_back(acc->open(o, id));
}
```

and i get a "syntax error : identifier 'account' and "'acc' : undeclared identifier error.

this .cpp has 
    `#include "bank.h"` which has `#include "bank_account.h"` (which is the banks personal account) which has `#include "account.h"`, and there is absolutely no way for a circular reference.

if I type `account::` the scope is visible, and if I right click and search for the declaration it (VS 2008) finds it.

here is the `account.h` class declaration

```
class account
{
public:
account(void) {}
~account(void) {}

int number;
int password;
int bal;

//void openAccount(op *o, int id);
void deposit(int amount, int id);
int withdraw(int amount, int id);
void balance(int id);
void close(int id);
int comission(float percentage);
void log(int msg, int id, int amount=0);
};
```

Thanks for any help...

Comment: Not the major error, but still:  If the account exists, you return ACCOUNT_EXISTS;   If not, you don't return anything at all!  But you are contracted to return an int.

Comment: thank you for the quick replies! i have edited the original question with the account class. the problematic line is the one with "acc" in it in the first segment of code.

Comment: Does `account` name both a type and a member object?

Comment: no, bank has a "bank_account _account;", but no account.

Comment: Then what does `o->account` refer to?

Comment: that was it Kerrek, thanks a bunch, pretty embarrassed I missed that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, on this line:

```
accounts.push_back(acc->open(o, id));
```

You are calling `acc->open()`, and `acc` is of type `account*`.
But I do not see any definition for method `open` in class `account`.
Therefore, you cannot call the `open` via the `acc` pointer.


The closest match is the method `openAccount`, but that is currently commented out, and cannot be used.

---

Secondly, your code calls `accounts.push_back()`.
But as far as the code you've shown us, `bank` does not have a member `accounts`.
You'll need to show us that part too.

Comment: `acc` is of type `account*`.  Levels of indirection are important.

Answer (score 0):

1. try to include `account.h` in the cpp file in questions. It's better to include what you use and not to rely on other include files to include things for you.
2. It seems that you are leaking `account` objects. They are never freed (regardless if the account exists or not)

Could it be that the `account` class is in a different namespace?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that some of your headers have the same header guards?  It looks like you think a header should be included but it isn't.

So make sure that you don't have

```
#if !defined( BANK_H )  
#define BANK_H

#endif //BANK_H
```

Or something similar in multiple files.  Each header file should have guards, but not the same ones :)